# Jquery randomly stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright, I've been working on a jQuery script all day, mostly tweaking it to get the errors to show properly, and all of a sudden---the code just stopped working. The form isn't submitting or anything.

Below I've included the code; I'm assuming its something on the jQuery side (namely google or something) because I reverted the code to the last working configuration and still am not getting anything.

Edit: There is no console error, the jQuery is not submitting. That is the problem i am having.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Login Test</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='theme/default/style.css' />
</head>
<div id='alert' class='hidden'>
Error
</div>
<body>
<div id='welcome_holder'>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id='welcome'>
<form method='post' action='actionlog.php' id='login'>
<tr>
<th colspan='3'><h3>Citizen Login</h3></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='user'>Username</td><td class="user">:</td><td class="user"><input type='text' name='username' id='username'></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td class='pass'>Password</td><td class="pass">:</td><td class="pass"><input type='password' name='password' id='password'></td>
</tr>
<tr><th colspan='3'><input type='submit' /></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan='3'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Don't have an account? <a href='register.php'>Register Today!</a><br /> Forgotten Password/Username?</span></th>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#login').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'actionlog.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                  username: $('#username').val(),
                  password: $('#password').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 'true')
                { location.reload(); } 
                else
                {
                    $('#alert').addClass('show');
                }

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why do you have alert div outside the body?

Comment: What's the console say about this?

Comment: Rather than having your form in a table put the table in the form.

Comment: Your html is not valid. Try to format it properly and run through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/). If you still have the issue, look at the error in console (F12) and provide it as part of your question.

Comment: Please give us your console log; when you reverted the code, you might have missed a spot. Also, check and make sure that jQuery is at the path you give; even if you're sure, weird things can happen. Anyway, giving a console log is the first thing you should do when you post an error report; it contains vital information, even if it makes no sense to you whatsoever.

Comment: By the way, when I looked at your code, the HTML spirit within me died. Please debug your HTML; browsers don't have to accept malformed code, even if your browser does. Check out the validator that Maksim posted.

Comment: The console says nothing about it. I thought i said that in the original post, i guess I forgot. The code just decided to stop sending through, to stop working at all. With no reason, no errors, no nothing. If i turn off the jquery and just have the code run through the login script by itself, it works fine. but with the jquery, as of 8:35 EST, it just stopped working.

Comment: Was the HTML changed in a way that may break JS (like a change to an `id`)? Is the HTML syntax correct? Improper HTML may break JS code easily and silently. Make sure jQuery is being loaded, too.

Comment: show us the HTML please. Also you should check out `serializeArray()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: How is that not valid viper. Enlighten me. Or should I tell you now that // acts like a wild card and excepts http or https requests. This is the default on google cdn.

Comment: Vikengben The link provided doesn't exist.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Try a different browser. Maybe yours was updated at 8:35 and stopped interpreting the invalid markup as expected?

Answer (score 0):

there were a couple issues with the code, the first thing that is to bind to dom events once the document is ready. Most importantly when submitting a form, you need to prevent the event using `event.preventDefault()` this stops the browser for performing the action of the form using the method of the form (aka posting to a url) I have update the code to reflect these changes, also fixed the HTML based on comments to your question.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Test</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='theme/default/style.css' />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    // use $(document).ready(function(){}) 
    // $(function(){}) is a shortcut for ready function
    $(function(){
        $('#login').submit(function(e) {
            // stop the form from submitting and allow the ajax to run
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'actionlog.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                      username: $('#username').val(),
                      password: $('#password').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == 'true')
                    { 
                        location.reload(); 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        $('#alert').addClass('show');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- alert div needs to be in body tag -->
    <div id='alert' class='hidden'>Error</div>
    <div id='welcome_holder'>
        <!-- form outside of table -->
        <form method='post' action='actionlog.php' id='login'>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id='welcome'>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='3'><h3>Citizen Login</h3></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='user'>Username</td>
                    <td class="user">:</td>
                    <td class="user"><input type='text' name='username' id='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='pass'>Password</td>
                    <td class="pass">:</td>
                    <td class="pass"><input type='password' name='password' id='password'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='3'><input type='submit' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='3'>
                        <span style='font-size: 12px;'>Don't have an account? <a href='register.php'>Register Today!</a><br /> Forgotten Password/Username?</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```